# Неправильная отрисовка бесконечного RecyclerView | Kotlin | DiscreteScrollView

Tags: xml, kotlin, recyclerview, slider, discretescrollview

Использую **сторонную** библиотеку (**DiscreteScrollView**) для создания слайдера. Слайдер бесконечный, но технически работает правильно.

Всего **15 изображений** и когда **число** внизу **доходит** до **15**, то переходит **на 1**. Но вот **с изображениями** проблема. Иногда они **не отрисовывают** (думаю, что все же отрисовываются, но где-то далеко), а если и отрисовались **в нужном месте**, то не работают также, как и цифры (после 15 картинки идут **белые блоки**).

**Что делать?**

Xml:

```
        <com.yarolegovich.discretescrollview.DiscreteScrollView
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:dsv_orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />
```

Инициализация:

```
        sliderView = root.findViewById(R.id.slider)
        val adapter = RatingSliderAdapter()
        adapter.list = placeholder(15)
        val wrapper = InfiniteScrollAdapter.wrap(adapter)
        sliderView.apply {
            this.adapter = wrapper
            addOnItemChangedListener { _, _ ->
                positionView.apply {
                    text = (wrapper.realCurrentPosition + 1).toString()
                }
            }
        }
        sliderView.setSlideOnFling(true)
        sliderView.setSlideOnFlingThreshold(1000)
        sliderView.setItemTransformer(
            ScaleTransformer.Builder()
                .setMaxScale(1f)
                .setMinScale(0.8f)
                .build()
        )
```

Скрин: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в адаптере. Я через Glide получал изображение, но  не заметил, что строкой ниже меняю его на просто белый цвет.